# Lipschitz Continuity Contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Show that $f\colon (0, \infty) \to\mathbb R$ defined by $f (x) := \frac1x$ is not Lipschitz continuous.
I have the following:

$$\left|\frac1x - \frac1y\right| = \left|\frac{y-x}{xy}\right| = \frac1{xy}\cdot |x-y|$$
I know that making the denominator $xy$ as small as possibly will make the who quotient sufficiently large, however I am having trouble conceptualizing why this causing a contradiction in the definition of Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: or else you can use the fact that it is not uniform continuous!

Comment: What do you find if you put that next to the definition of Lipschitz continuity?

Comment: does the Lipschitz constant have to be sufficiently small by definition?

Comment: @user72195: No. It does, however, have to be *constant*.

Comment: so because the bounds are (0,infinity) the constant will continue to grow large which is the contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

In the definition of Lipschitz function we read $$\exists L\ge 0:\, \forall x\,\forall y \, |f(x)-f(y)|\le L|x-y|.$$

If such $L$ existed for our case, then we would take $x,y\le \frac {1}{2}\sqrt {1/L}$ to obtain

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=\frac{|x-y|}{xy}\ge 4L|x-y|,$$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can observe that

$ |f(x) - f(y) | = \frac{1}{xy} |x - y| \le L | x - y |  $ IFF

$ \exists L \ge \frac{1}{xy} $

but the domain allows $ x \rightarrow 0 $ so that L doesn't exist